# How get the row number in certain column in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my spreadsheet I have 12 sheets. Every sheet is called by the name of a city. It also appears in the column A in every sheet with its corresponding name.

To localize the row number in vba, I use this code.

```
Q = 0

 For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 

    //Result is the last sheet
   If Sheet.Name <> "Result" Then

    With Sheet      
        number = .Range("A:A").Find(Sheet.Name).Row + 1
    totalnumber = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Q = Q + (number - totalnumber + 1) * 31
          //I use this for get the date from a month
          For i = 1 To 12
            If arr(i) = .Range("a2") Then    
               YY = Year(Now)
               MM = Month(CDate("01/" & i & "/" & YY))
               Exit For
            End If
          Next
      End With
   End If
Next
```

I need this code, in format javascript of google apps script.

I tried this

```
var Hc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Hn= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();

number = Hc.getRange('A:A'), Find(Hn), Row + 1;
totalnumber = Hc.getRange('A' & Rows.Count), Hc.End(xlUp), Hc.Row
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? show us your javascript code

Comment: Done, i put my tried.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, you need a function:

   ```
   function myFunction() {
     // next code will be written here, line by line
   }
   ```
2. Then, you need to open your spreadsheet.

   ```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lqLHXt15SKamuGTnIjQoAAiWuuxEJOUcY1ZdamxCk_0"); // you can actually use this id. Link below the post.
   ```

   From here on, `ss` will be our spreadsheet
3. Then you need to get all your sheets

   ```
   var allMySheets = ss.getSheets();
   ```

   `allMySheets` is now an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) - each element being a sheet from our spreadsheet.
4. Now we need to go through each of the sheet. There are [various ways to iterate in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), but we will use a `forEach` method in this example:

   ```
   allMySheets.forEach(function(sheet){
     //                         ^ note
     // next code will be written here, line by line
   })
   ```

   What this does is calls the inner function for each element in `allMySheets` and provides that function the element as an argument. From here on, `sheet` is our sheet.
5. [You can do all sorts of stuff on a `Sheet` object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). We need its name using [`getName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getName()):

   ```
   var sheetName = sheet.getName();
   ```
6. We also need the range that contains the data:

   ```
   var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
   ```
7. And the actual values:

   ```
   var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
   ```
8. `dataValues` is now a bidimensional array and looks something like this:

   ```
   [
     ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"],
     ["Some val", "Some val2", 15],
     [3,8,0],
   ]
   ```

   And translates into the actual table that you see in that sheet:

   ```
   +----------+-----------+----------+
   | Column 1 | Column 2  | Column 3 |
   +----------+-----------+----------+
   | Some val | Some val2 |       15 |
   | 3        | 8         |        0 |
   +----------+-----------+----------+
   ```

   We need to loop over this. We'll use two `for` loops. First one will represents rows, and the other for columns:

   ```
   for (var i=0;i<dataValues.length;i++){
     var rowArray = dataValues[i];
     for (var j=0;j<rowArray.length;j++){
       var columnValue = rowArray[j];
     }
   }
   ```

   If `i` is 0, means we're at 1<sup>st</sup> row, if it's 1 2<sup>nd</sup> row, etc. because arrays in most programming languages, JavaScript included, are 0 based indexed.

   Same applies for columns. `j` being `0` means we're at first column.

   Here's the same thing visualized

   ```
             j = 0      j = 1      j = 2
         +----------+-----------+----------+
   i = 0 | Column 1 | Column 2  | Column 3 |
         +----------+-----------+----------+
   i = 1 | Some val | Some val2 |       15 |
   i = 2 | 3        | 8         |        0 |
         +----------+-----------+----------+
   ```
9. Enough theory. Back to our needs, we care about first column containing the sheet name. That is, if `j` is `0`, we need it's data. That means:

   ```
   if (j===0) {
     // we are at first column
     // let's check if the value is our sheetName:

     if (columnValue === sheetName){
       // if we got here, means we have the needed row. 
       var rowNumber = i + 1; // remember that in array, i being 0 meneans row one
       Logger.log(rowNumber);

       // now you can do whatever you want to this number.
     }
   }
   ```

   Or, another approach (I recommend this one, because it's easier to use other column values from the same row:

   ```
   if (rowArray[0] === sheetName){
     // We're at the right row 
     var rowNumber = i+1;

     // Do something with columnValue

   }
   ```

And that's it. Here's  the whole code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lqLHXt15SKamuGTnIjQoAAiWuuxEJOUcY1ZdamxCk_0");
  var allMySheets = ss.getSheets();
  allMySheets[0].getRange(1, 1, allMySheets[0].getLastRow(), allMySheets[0].getLastColumn()).getValues()
  allMySheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i=0;i<dataValues.length;i++){
      var rowArray = dataValues[i];
      for (var j=0;j<rowArray.length;j++){
        var columnValue = rowArray[j];

        if (rowArray[0] === sheetName){
          // We're at the right row 
          var rowNumber = i+1;
          Logger.log("Row number: %s, sheet name: %s, column value: %s", rowNumber, sheetName, columnValue);
          // Do something with columnValue

        }

      }
    }
  })
}
```

Here's [the spreadsheet with  the code embedded](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lqLHXt15SKamuGTnIjQoAAiWuuxEJOUcY1ZdamxCk_0/edit#gid=0).